# Error: two or more data types in declaration of 'x'

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm compiling a C++ program which and I get the error "two or more data types in declaration" at the line below. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
List SplitInflix(const string infix)
{
List tokenlist;
string word= "";
char x;
for (char x : infix)
    {
    switch (x)
    {
    case '(':
        if (word != "")
        {
            Token* token = new Token(word);
            tokenlist.append(token);
            word = "";
            Token * token1 = new Token(LEFT);
            tokenlist.append(token1);
        }
        else
        {
            Token * token = new Token(LEFT);
            tokenlist.append(token);
        }
        break;
    ...
}
return tokenlist;
}
```

I get the error:

> error: two or more data types in declaration of 'x'

There's more coding but it's too long and I think it's not related to the error.

How do I fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Why this line before for loop: `char x;`? Is that line needed?

Comment: Please remove all the code that is not related to the error. I.e., remove lines until we can all just copy, paste, compile and get just *that* error. Read about what a [mcve] is. You currently don't have one.

Comment: @kiner_shah if [char x] wasnt there the error would be [x is not declared in this scope]

Comment: On which line is the error shown?

Comment: @StoryTeller i though if all the part would be easier, sorry and thank you

Comment: Very good first step. But still not a [mcve]. `Token` is unidentified, as is `List`. And `...` is a syntactic error. Remember, if we can all get the error by copy and pasting your code as is, we can help you promptly. BTW, what compiler are you using?

Comment: "*if [char x] wasnt there the...*". Did you try removing that line?

Answer (score 0):

`for(:)` is ***range-based*** for loop and is a [`c++ 11` feature](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) of the language. So use of bellow insted of `for(:)` statement :

```
for each (char x in infix)
```

As far as I know, `for(:)` is compatible with `g++` compiler and it may be incompatible with anyother compilers.

Then remove `x` declaration from code :

```
List SplitInflix(const string infix)
{
List tokenlist;
string word= "";
// char x;       Theres no need to this line
for each (char x in infix)
    {
    switch (x)
    {
    case '(':
        if (word != "")
        {
            Token* token = new Token(word);
            tokenlist.append(token);
            word = "";
            Token * token1 = new Token(LEFT);
            tokenlist.append(token1);
        }
        else
        {
            Token * token = new Token(LEFT);
            tokenlist.append(token);
        }
        break;
    ...
}
return tokenlist;
}
```

Comment: if [char x] wasnt there the error would be [x is not declared in this scope

Comment: @YasakaMagatama I improved my answer, see it again please